# check whether a string is in a 2-GB list of strings in python

Tags: python

I have a large file (`A.txt`) of 2 GB containing a list of strings `['Question','Q1','Q2','Q3','Ans1','Format','links',...]`.

Now I have another larger file(1TB) containing the above mentioned strings in 2nd position:

Output:

```
a, Question, b
The, quiz, is
This, Q1, Answer
Here, Ans1, is
King1, links, King2
programming,language,drupal,
.....
```

I want to retain the lines whose second position contain the strings in the list stored in file `A.txt`. That is, I want to retain (store in another file) the below mentioned lines:

```
a, Question, b
This, Q1, Answer
Here, Ans1, is
King1, links, King2
```

I know how to do this when the length of the list in file (A.txt) is 100..using 'any'. But I am not getting how I should go about it when the length of the list in file (A.txt) is 2 GB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use a list; use a set instead.

Read the first file into a set:

```
with open('A.txt') as file_a:
    words = {line.strip() for line in file_a}
```

0.5 GB of words isn't *that* much to store in a set.

Now you can test against `words` in O(1) constant time:

```
if second_word in words:
    # ....
```

Open the second file and process it line by line, perhaps using the `csv` module if the lines words are comma-separated.

For a larger set of words, use a database instead; Python comes with the `sqlite3` library:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE words (word UNIQUE)')

with open('A.txt') as file_a, conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for line in file_a:
        cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO words VALUES (?)', (line.strip(),))
```

then test against that:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for line in second_file:
    second_word = hand_waving
    cursor.execute('SELECT 1 from words where word=?', (second_word,))
    if cursor.fetchone():
         # ....
```

Even though I use a `:memory:` database here, SQLite is smart enough to store data in temporary files when you start filling up memory. The `:memory:` connection is basically just a temporary, one-off database. You can also use a real filepath if you want to re-use the words database.

Comment: @JonClements: Fallback option, sqlite.

Comment: Not really necessary but the query could be rewritten as an IN/ANY or EXISTS  - or if one has a redis or similar server handy that'd work nicely...

Comment: @JonClements: I don't think `EXISTS` is going to help here; then I have to actually fetch that value and test for that column. Now I just have to test if there is anything being returned (`.fetchone()` will return `None` if there was no result). The `UNIQUE` constraint and the automatic index that I just added will help more here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Start with the answer by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16823273/5987). If that's too slow you can use a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to cut down the number of times you use the database, by eliminating lines that can't possibly match any words in your list. Python comes with a built-in [`hash` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash) that you can use for one of the hashes into the filter table, and you can look up any number of others.