# How to use strings from one text file to search another, and create a new text file with columns from another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to use strings from one text file to search another, and every time the string matches in the second text file, search the second string for a word `word`, and if that matches, to create a third text file with specific columns from the second text file, and repeat for every string in the first text file.

**Example**

Text file 1:

```
10.2.1.1
10.2.1.2
10.2.1.3
```

Text file 2:

```
IP=10.2.1.4 word=apple thing=car name=joe
IP=10.2.1.3 word=apple thing=car name=joe
IP=10.2.1.1 word=apple thing=car name=joe
IP=10.2.1.2 word=apple thing=car name=joe
IP=10.2.1.1 word=apple thing=car name=joe
IP=10.2.1.3 word=apple thing=car name=joe
```

Result should be three separate text files (named for their string in text file one), one for each string containing the third column:

Result: 10.2.1.3.txt

```
thing=car
thing=car
```

etc.

So far my code looks like:

```
with open(file_1) as list_file:
    for string in (line.strip() for line in list_file):
        if string in file_2:
            if "word" in file_2:            
                column2 = line.split()[2]
                x = open(line+".txt", "a")
                with x as new_file:
                    new_file.write(column2)
```

My question is: Is this code the best way to do it? I feel as though there's an important 'shortcut' I'm missing.

**Final Code** with *Olafur Osvaldsson*:

```
for line_1 in open(file_1):
    with open(line_1+'.txt', 'a') as my_file:
        for line_2 in open(file_2):
            line_2_split = line_2.split(' ')
            if "word" in line_2:
                if "word 2" in line_2:
                    my_file.write(line_2_split[2] + '\n')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [check whether a string is in a 2-GB list of strings in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823214/check-whether-a-string-is-in-a-2-gb-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: That does have some of what I'm asking, though not in total.

Comment: What is `file_2` in your existing code? By analogy with `file_1` it looks like a filename, in which case the whole thing is rather silly. If it's the contents of a file that you've read into memory, you're not doing anything line by line; you're just checking the entire file at once. Is that what you want? (If so, why do the check for `"word"` over and over, when it's obviously never going to change?)

Comment: @hjames: no, but the efficiency principles apply. It is not a fully coded-up solution but the *architecture* is there.

Comment: @abarnert: you're right, I have neglected to check `file_2` line by line, would you recommend doing that with `.readlines()`?

Comment: @hjames: No, `readlines()` is bad. I'd recommend reading one file into an appropriate data structure that makes the relevant searches easy, and then iterating the other file line by line. I'm not sure whether mtadd's answer does what you want to do, but it is definitely the right kind of structure: it creates a dict out of file1, then is looks things up in that dict for each line in file2. It's very rare that a list of lines (which is what `readlines` gives you) is the right data structure, and even on those rare occasions, it's better to be explicit and write `lines = list(f)`.

Comment: I'll write a solution, but first please clear my doubts. Do you always want to match the IP field in a line in the second file and if it matches then write some other fields from that line to file named with that IP?

Comment: @pkacprzak: yes, there is the second check, after the IP field first matches in the second file, it also has to match the specified word before the columns are written to the new file named with the IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code I believe does what you ask:

```
file_1='file1.txt'
file_2='file2.txt'

my_string = 'word'

for line_1 in [l.rstrip() for l in open(file_1)]:
    with open(line_1+'.txt', 'a') as my_file:
        for line_2 in open(file_2):
            line_2_split = line_2.split(' ')
            if line_1 == line_2_split[0][3:]:
                if my_string in line_2:
                    my_file.write(line_2_split[2] + '\n')
```

If you intend on using the last parameter in the lines from `file_2` make sure you strip the newline from the end like is done to the first file with `rstrip()`, I left it in the lines from `file_2`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, with input files in *file1.txt* and *file2.txt*.  I cache the contents of file 1, and their associate output file handles in the **dictionary** 'files', which I then close at the end after the main loop.

In the main loop, I read in each line of *file2.txt*, strip it, and tokenize it on spaces using the **split** method.  I then find the ip address from the first token, and check if its in 'files'.  If so, I write the third column to the respective output file.

The last loop closes the output file handles.

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    files = {ip:open(ip + '.txt', 'w') for ip in [line.strip() for line in file1]}

with open('file2.txt') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        tokens = line.strip().split(' ')
        ip = tokens[0][3:]
        if ip in files:
            files[ip].write(tokens[2])
            files[ip].write('\r\n')

for f in files.values():
    f.close()
```

Comment: What exactly does ip = `tokens[0][3:]` do - how does it find the IP address? thanks!

Comment: tokens[0] is the first column (the text before the first space), the [3:] specifies the range from the fourth index to the end (ranges are zero based, i.e., the first element is 0), this strips off the 'IP=' prefix from the first column.

Answer (score 1):

```
# define files
file1 = "file1.txt"
file2 = "file2.txt"

ip_patterns = set() # I assume that all patterns fits the memory

# filling ip_patterns
with open(file1) as fp:
    for line in fp: 
        ip_patterns.add(line.strip()) # adding pattern to the set


word_to_match = "apple" # pattern for the "word" field
wanted_fields = ['name', 'thing'] # fields to write

with open(file2) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        values = dict(map(lambda x: x.split('='), line.split()))
        if values['IP'] in ip_patterns and values['word'] == word_to_match:
            out = open(values['IP'] + '.txt', 'a')
            for k in wanted_fields:
                out.write("%s=%s\n" % (k, values[k])) # writing to file
            out.close()
```

Comment: That brings error: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Comment: @hjames for what input?

Comment: `values = dict(map(lambda x: x.split('='), line.split()))` I believe

Comment: @hjames I asked for what input files the above code produces the ValueError